# opencv-python: haveOpenCL return False

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

Should return `True` if the the prebuilt binaries are compiled with OpenCL support. I've seen many [examples](https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/) where it just works out of the box. So my assumption is that the binaries are built with OpenCL support. So why might it not be working for me?

Also it works from C++ for OpenCV installed from source. So my computer has OpenCV runtime installed:

> [ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...

opencv-python version: `3.4.2`

Comment: The best way to be sure that OpenCL is in the prebuilt python binaries is to write: `print (cv2.getBuildInformation())` and to look for the OpenCL tag.

Comment: I ran this command and found that `Use OpenCL: NO` was present. So how do I get opencv-python to build binaries with OpenCL support?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake.

Turns out I've been using the cv2 from anaconda. There I get:

> Use Cuda:                    NO
>
> Use OpenCL:                  NO

When using cv2 from `opencv-python` I get:

> OpenCL:                      YES (no extra features)
>
> Include path:                NO
>
> Link libraries:              -framework OpenCL

Comment: Thanks for answering it yourself though!